# How can I just change the blue color of input Range?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change to the blue color which is in the default input range.

```html
<input type='range' id="input"/>
```

Is it possible to just change the blue color of the slider and thumb in the input range?

I have seen many answers but no one shows how to just change the blue color in of the slider and thumb the input range.

Please help me

Comment: In chrome it's white/gray instead!

Comment: No it's blue and white

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73140639/8257973).

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in style

```
#input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}


#input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  border-radius:50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can see slider like below

[image]

Comment: No, I just want to change the blue color, every thing should remain the same