# Input range slider progress for Chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I am working on an input type range slider. I found out that the Chrome version of `input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb` is `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb` .

Now, I want the same for `input[type=range]::-moz-range-progress`.

I have tried `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-progress` , `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-progress` .

Still not working so far. Any alternative?

Comment: Have you tried `::-webkit-progress-value { background-color: orange; }`

Comment: @martinho No, but I just did and it didn't work.

Comment: With `input[type=range]::-webkit-progress-value { background-color: orange; }` add `input[type=range] { -webkit-appearance: none; }` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-value

Comment: ::-webkit-progress-value is only for <progress /> elements not input types of range.

Answer (score 8):

It is totally possible with CSS only.

This dude has done it: https://codepen.io/ShadowShahriar/pen/zYPPYrQ

HTML:

```
<main>
    <input type="range" class="win10-thumb" />
    <input type="range" class="win10-thumb" min="0" max="100" value="25" step="5" />
    <input type="range" class="win10-thumb" disabled value="64" />
    <input type="range" />
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="40" step="5" />
    <input type="range" disabled value="80" />
</main>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2.2em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

html::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #fff, #fafafa);
    display: block;
}

/* === range theme and appearance === */
input[type="range"] {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 12.5em;
}

input[type="range"] {
    color: #ef233c;
    --thumb-height: 1.125em;
    --track-height: 0.125em;
    --track-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    --brightness-hover: 180%;
    --brightness-down: 80%;
    --clip-edges: 0.125em;
}

input[type="range"].win10-thumb {
    color: #2b2d42;

    --thumb-height: 1.375em;
    --thumb-width: 0.5em;
    --clip-edges: 0.0125em;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    html::before {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #101112, #000);
    }

    input[type="range"] {
        color: #f07167;
        --track-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    input[type="range"].win10-thumb {
        color: #3a86ff;
    }
}

/* === range commons === */
input[type="range"] {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="range"]:active {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]:disabled {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    opacity: 0.3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* === WebKit specific styles === */
input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transition: all ease 100ms;
    height: var(--thumb-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    --thumb-radius: calc((var(--thumb-height) * 0.5) - 1px);
    --clip-top: calc((var(--thumb-height) - var(--track-height)) * 0.5 - 0.5px);
    --clip-bottom: calc(var(--thumb-height) - var(--clip-top));
    --clip-further: calc(100% + 1px);
    --box-fill: calc(-100vmax - var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height))) 0 0
        100vmax currentColor;

    width: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    background: linear-gradient(currentColor 0 0) scroll no-repeat left center /
        50% calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
    background-color: currentColor;
    box-shadow: var(--box-fill);
    border-radius: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));

    filter: brightness(100%);
    clip-path: polygon(
        100% -1px,
        var(--clip-edges) -1px,
        0 var(--clip-top),
        -100vmax var(--clip-top),
        -100vmax var(--clip-bottom),
        0 var(--clip-bottom),
        var(--clip-edges) 100%,
        var(--clip-further) var(--clip-further)
    );
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-hover));
    cursor: grab;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-down));
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--track-color) 0 0) scroll no-repeat center /
        100% calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* === Firefox specific styles === */
input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    transition: all ease 100ms;
    height: var(--thumb-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background: #fff0;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: currentColor;
    border: 0;
    width: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    border-radius: var(--thumb-width, var(--thumb-height));
    cursor: grab;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--track-color);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    appearance: none;
    background: currentColor;
    transition-delay: 30ms;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    height: calc(var(--track-height) + 1px);
    border-radius: var(--track-height);
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(100%);
}

input[type="range"]:hover::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]:hover::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-hover));
}

input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb,
input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-progress {
    filter: brightness(var(--brightness-down));
}

input[type="range"]:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: How to add borderRadius?

Answer (score 2):

On Internet Explorer you can use `::-ms-fill-lower` to do this thing and firefox supports `::-moz-range-progress`, but on chrome this is not possible only using css.

However, there is a good example below using JS.
It changes the background of the range element using `linear-gradient`.
https://codepen.io/duplich/pen/qjYQEZ

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`accent-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color)

```css
input[type="range"] {
  accent-color : red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: doesn't work with the use of `appearance : none;` to customize  track and thumb elements